# C string manipulation for removing xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx

Tags: c, string

I have a problem removing a substring `xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx` from one main string. Here is the background info for the problem:

in a function void `funA()`:

```
void funA(const char* sth){
 if (sth == THINGA){
      // do A;
    }
 else if (sth == THINGB){
      // do B;
    }
eles{
      // do C;
    }
 log_status("current status: - %s", sth);
}
```

sth is a string contains a substring in the format of `xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx` where x is either a number or a letter. The substring has a space in front of it but might not have one at the end of the string. I need to obfuscate this substring with a `*`. Since only the substring has `:`, I made a helper function to locate the first `:` and the last `:` and remove 2 characters before it. Delete the last 2 characters and append a `*`. I think this way is most the best solution. So I'm wondering if there are any more efficient design of a helper function aka a helper function has shorter runtime and uses less memory. Since the substring xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx has a very distinguish format, the only easier way I can think of is to do a string match to find the substring and then replace it with a `*`. I'm open to other more innovative way though.

Comment: If you have a helper function, you should post the helper function.

Comment: `eles` --> `else`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#ifndef PARSER_STACK_H_INCLUDED
#define PARSER_STACK_H_INCLUDED


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define PATTERN_LEN 18


typedef struct{
    unsigned int start;
    unsigned int finish;
}index;

void remove_str_pattern(char *original, char *extract, unsigned int start, unsigned int finish);
void splitter(char *x, index *index_SF);
unsigned int count_points(const char *x);
void obscure(char *str, index index_SF);
char* return_obscure_string(char *str);
char* return_pattern(char *str);

char* return_pattern(char *str){
    index index_SF = {0,0};

    char *str_export = calloc(PATTERN_LEN, sizeof(char));
    char *tmp = calloc(sizeof(str)/sizeof(char), sizeof(char));

    strcpy(tmp, str);

    splitter(str, &index_SF);

    obscure(tmp, index_SF);
    remove_str_pattern(str, str_export, index_SF.start, index_SF.finish);

    return str_export;
}

char* return_obscure_string(char *str){
    index index_SF = {0,0};

    char *str_export = calloc(PATTERN_LEN, sizeof(char));
    char *tmp = calloc(sizeof(str)/sizeof(char), sizeof(char));

    strcpy(tmp, str);

    splitter(str, &index_SF);

    obscure(tmp, index_SF);
    remove_str_pattern(str, str_export, index_SF.start, index_SF.finish);

    return tmp;
}

void obscure(char *str, index index_SF){
   for(unsigned int i = index_SF.start; i < index_SF.finish+1; ++i){
        if(str[i] != ':'){
            str[i] = '*';
        }
    }
}

void splitter(char *x, index *index_SF){
    for(unsigned int i = 0, tmp = 0; i < strlen(x); ++i){
        if(x[i] == ':'){
            ++tmp;
            if(tmp == 1){
                index_SF->start = i-2;
            }else{
                if(tmp == 5){
                    index_SF->finish = i+2;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

unsigned int count_points(const char *x){
    int c = 1;

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < strlen(x); ++i){
        if((x[i] == ':' && x[i+2] == ':') || (x[i] == ':' && x[i-2] == ':')){
            ++c;
        }
    }
    return c;
}

void remove_str_pattern(char *original, char *extract, unsigned int start, unsigned int finish){
    for(unsigned int i = start, j = 0; i < finish+1; ++i, ++j){
        extract[j] = original[i];
    }
}

#endif // PARSER_STACK_H_INCLUDED
```

That is my personal header file for your request, create header file with this code and try it ! :D
Two "main" functions of this file are.
**1. char* return_obscure_string(char *str);**
*For return original string with obscured sub-string..*

**2. char* return_pattern(char *str);**
*For return pattern value from a string..*

Good Luck Man !

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define PATTERN_LEN 18

typedef struct{
    unsigned int start;
    unsigned int finish;
}index;

void remove_str_pattern(char *original, char *extract, unsigned int start, unsigned int finish);
void splitter(char *x, index *index_SF);
unsigned int count_points(const char *x);
void obscure(char *str, index index_SF);

void main(){
    index index_SF = {0,0};
    char *origin = "this is first try for me in stack aa:bb:22:44:55:66 overflow...";
    char *str_export = calloc(PATTERN_LEN, sizeof(char));
    char *tmp = calloc(sizeof(origin)/sizeof(char), sizeof(char));

    strcpy(tmp, origin);

    splitter(origin, &index_SF);

    obscure(tmp, index_SF);

    remove_str_pattern(origin, str_export, index_SF.start, index_SF.finish);

    printf("start index: %u finish index: %u\n", index_SF.start, index_SF.finish);
    printf("obscured string %s\n", tmp);
    printf("original str: %s\n", origin);
    printf("pattern: %s\n", str_export);

}

void obscure(char *str, index index_SF){
   for(unsigned int i = index_SF.start; i < index_SF.finish+1; ++i){
        if(str[i] != ':'){
            str[i] = '*';
        }
    }
}

void splitter(char *x, index *index_SF){
    for(unsigned int i = 0, tmp = 0; i < strlen(x); ++i){
        if(x[i] == ':'){
            ++tmp;
            if(tmp == 1){
                index_SF->start = i-2;
            }else{
                if(tmp == 5){
                    index_SF->finish = i+2;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

unsigned int count_points(const char *x){
    int count = 1;

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < strlen(x); ++i){
        if((x[i] == ':' && x[i+2] == ':') || (x[i] == ':' && x[i-2] == ':')){
            ++count;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

void remove_str_pattern(char *original, char *extract, unsigned int start, unsigned int finish){
    for(unsigned int i = start, j = 0; i < finish+1; ++i, ++j){
        extract[j] = original[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @roothunter this is a great function and I really appreciate your help. Just one follow up, could you help me modify this function into a helper function please? For example `char *helper(char *inStr) {...}`. And the function return the result string